# display a taxonomy as an image

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

Hi Im using taxonomies for categorize my products with drupal commerce, Im using "Brand" vocabulary for the products I want to display a thumbnail of the brand instead of the name of the brand in text, for use in views when showing the products in a catalog, or in the main page of the product display when editing the display of the product display...

Any idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Entity Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) which will allow you to add an image field to the taxonomy.

Then instead of displaying the `term->name` you'll be able to display your image.

You can create a field image `field_brand_logo` and get it this way :

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$brand_logo = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_brand_logo');
if (!empty($brand_logo)) {
   $brand_logo_img = field_view_value('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_brand_logo', $brand_logo[0], array('type' => 'image'));
}

print render($brand_logo_img);
```

Comment: Hope it will fit your needs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1224916

Comment: that module is deprecated for drupal 7, could you tell me the steps?

Comment: Sorry, revised answer, looks like 'imagefield' does the same thing in 7...